# Can you style two different alternating table row heights in CSS?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I'm trying to create a table where every other row is about 1/3 the height of the preceding one. I can style this using an inline method, but was wondering if you can create a tag for different tr styles within the same table.

Thanks

Comment: You can give the alternate rows with different classnames and then set the height for the cells from the CSS.

Comment: @sarcastyx No need to do that, you can see my solution, what you are suggesting will be a messy approach

Comment: @Mr.Alien, sorry I am still stuck in a job where I have to deal with IE7. Hence my suggestion for alternating row class names.

Comment: @sarcastyx For that too, you can use CSS3 pie :)

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can do that by using CSS pseudo classes like `:nth-child(odd)` and `nth-child(even)` respectively.

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/MH2x6/)</kbd>

```
td {
    border: 1px solid #f00;
}

tr:nth-child(odd) {
    height: 100px;
}
```

and you can use `even` if you want to target the even ones..

```
tr:nth-child(even) {
    height: 100px;
}
```

Note that the above selectors will target ALL the `tr` and `td` elements on your document, so make sure you use `class` or an `id` to target the `table` uniquely like

```
.table-class tr:nth-child(odd) {
    /* Styles goes here */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

read [nth-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/:nth-child) property

> `tr:nth-child(odd)` : Represents the odd rows of an HTML table.
>
> `tr:nth-child(even)` : Represents the even rows of an HTML table.

so try with below css

```
tr:nth-child(odd){ height: 100px }
tr:nth-child(even) {max-height: 33%;}
```

[Working DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/MH2x6/2/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this [nth child](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp)

But if your table i created dynamically or have many rows that won't be so easy :)

Maybe this would help then : [LESS](http://lesscss.org/)

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
.your-table-class tbody tr:nth-child(even) {
  line-height: 10px; // your 1/3 value here
}
```